# Delegate an array in QML

Tags: javascript, arrays, delegates, qml

I have an array, which is presented like: one,two,three; when printing them in console.
I want to delegate these as a ListView but don't know how?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kind of did what Amit told me to, but I should have been more specific since the real issue I had was the loop, which I've now resolved.

I just created a ListModel with just an ID. Then I ran the array trough a function from forEach, which added each of the items in the array to the already created ListModel. Done!

```
// create the listmodel to use
ListModel {
    id: playlistModel
}

// function that adds each playlist in the listmodel to show it in the app
function addtoPlaylistModel(element,index,array) {
    console.debug("Debug: Playlist #" + index + " = " + element);
    playlistModel.append({"id": index, "name": element});
}

    // get playlists in an array
    var playlist = playlist1,playlist2,playlist3
    console.debug("Debug: Playlists: "+playlist) //debug
    playlist.forEach(addtoPlaylistModel) // send each item on playlist array to the model to show it
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a normal text element as the delegate.
2. Keep the model empty.
3. On component loading, run a loop over the array and append the data into model using the [append](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-listmodel.html#append-method) method.

Try and let know if you get stuck at some point.